# Phonegap .ajax do not work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cordova

I tried so much so optimize the code but the ajax will not work. I test the js with some debug alerts before the ajax, and it worked! So only my ajax is not working in the Android apk created with phonegap.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
                var user_id = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
                 alert(user_id); //this works fine
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://marcelkipp.com/quizapp/userinfo.php?user_id="+user_id,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data.username); //this do not work
                        setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="menu.html";}, 3000);
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("FAIL");
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: I suspect you run into Cross Domain issues if you're running this inside an app ...you have to enable cross domain access on your server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043136/phonegap-cross-domain-ajax-with-phonegap-developer-app-and-cli

Comment: the functions inside the alert success and error are not working

Comment: `$.ajax` is from jQuery. Do you even load that?

Comment: yes. When i tried the app over the phonepag server in worked fine. but in the build android app this dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Now I know why my ajax failed.
I imported the jquery from Google libraries, i integrate the jquery-file in my www folder and it worked.